# Pack a pyarmor obfuscated script to exe

Tags: python-3.x, py2exe, pyarmor

I'm trying to turn a pyarmor Obfuscated python file  in a exe.
I tried with pyinstaller but doesn't worked. 
Anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 4):

According to pyarmor's documentary, the process of obfuscating and what pyinstaller does, are being done by using

`cd directory_of_your_file`

and than using

`pyarmor pack myfile.py`

from

- [https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/.../packing-obfuscated-scripts](https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#packing-obfuscated-scripts) or
- [https://github.com/dashingsoft/pyarmor/.../README.md](https://github.com/dashingsoft/pyarmor/blob/master/src/examples/README.md)

After doing that it will create a file (exe file) in "your directory" under "dist" folder.

Additionally you can do something like code below from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60391524/pyarmor-error-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x83-in-position-594-invalid-star) to use  pyinstaller's options.

```
pyarmor pack -e " --onedir --noconsole --icon icon.ico" myfile.py
```

I saw this example accidentally, while I was looking for it. Does any one know where to find anything about how to use additional options of pyinstaller with pyarmor?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my AVG antivirus.
Identified the created ***.exe*** file as infected:

```
 Win66:EVO-gen [Trj]
```

Simply within the anti-virus options I removed it from the anti-virus quarantine section, and set an exception for that file.