# PyArmor ERROR 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 594: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pyarmor

I am developing with Python, and tried to make an installer by typing the following command in PyArmor.

```
pyarmor pack -e " --onedir --noconsole --icon icon.ico -n testApp" main.py
```

Then I got the following error.

```
ERROR    'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 594: invalid start byte
```

There is no error when I type and execute `python main.py`.

An error occurs only when PyArmor is running.

What is the cause? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but changing the script execution folder solved the problem.

If I put main.py in C: \ Users \ username \ Documents \ testApp folder and `cd C: \ Users \ username \ Documents \ testApp`, then I get an error.

However, when I put main.py in C: \ Users \ username \ Desktop \ testApp folder and `cd C: \ Users \ username \ Desktop \ testApp`, the error disappeared.

It is very strange.

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the documentation: https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/questions.html#xxx-codec-can-t-decode-byte-0xxx

You should put at the beginning of the script: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it didn't work. I don't know why.

Comment: The output was rubbish. I tried it and it solved my problem thnx.