# Converting pyarmor to an exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyarmor

Hey so I have a python file and I'd like to convert it to a exe I tried using pyinstaller but that could be easily reverse engineered and I figured out that pyarmor would be my best option. I went over the documentation and it was super confusing and had stuff about change a spec file and I have no experience in that whatsoever. Can someone dumb it down to me?

Comment: Are you following [this](https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) guide? If so what step did you get stuck on? It all looks pretty straightforward and step-by-step to me.

Comment: oh yes but this just obfuscates it. I need to obfuscate it then convert it to a exe

Comment: How about the `Packing Obfuscated Scripts` step that uses `pyinstaller` though?

Comment: do you mean [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58334936/pack-a-pyarmor-obfuscated-script-to-exe) I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Nope, also "doesn't work" isn't useful info to be able to help you solve the issue with.

Comment: oh yeah haha im so sorry about that. So sorry to waste your time apparently I miss read the error [here](https://prnt.sc/ul96om) is a screenshot. I exceeded the byte limit. But if you don't mind can ya help do you know if I can somehow reduce bytes or compress it or something?

Comment: FYI errors and code should never be posted here as images, only text. Also that sounds like a separate question; however, if you don't want to pay for the full version, you could try to minify your Python code. Depends on how much space you need saved, though, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Oh thanks I forgot I could do that. I'm new here so I'll try putting it in text next time. Anyways thanks for your help